Error while trying to show the results using PySpark show function
I am trying to show my results in PySpark.
I am using Spark 3.5.1 and PySpark 3.5.1 with Java 8 installed and everything is well set.
Some answers suggesting adding this:
import findspark
findspark.init()

Or adding this to the config:
.config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled","true") \
.config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","10g") \

But I am still getting this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[42], line 3
      1 import findspark
      2 findspark.init()
----> 3 value_counts.show()

File ...new_env2\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:945, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    885 def show(self, n: int = 20, truncate: Union[bool, int] = True, vertical: bool = False) -> None:
    886     """Prints the first ``n`` rows to the console.
    887 
    888     .. versionadded:: 1.3.0
   (...)
    943     name | Bob
    944     """
--> 945     print(self._show_string(n, truncate, vertical))

File ...new_env2\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:963, in DataFrame._show_string(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    957     raise PySparkTypeError(
    958         error_class="NOT_BOOL",
    959         message_parameters={"arg_name": "vertical", "arg_type": type(vertical).__name__},
    960     )
    962 if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 963     return self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical)
    964 else:
    965     try:

File ...new_env2\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File ....new_env2\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~\OneDrive\Bureau\Desktop\big_data\big_data\new_env2\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o194.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 50) (Zaineb executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextAwareIterator.hasNext(ContextAwareIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.takeDestructively(Iterator.scala:1160)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.go(Iterator.scala:1176)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1214)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BasePythonUDFRunner$PythonUDFWriterThread.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:451)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1928)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:282)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:398)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
    ... 26 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2856)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2792)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3060)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:789)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:766)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextAwareIterator.hasNext(ContextAwareIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.takeDestructively(Iterator.scala:1160)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.go(Iterator.scala:1176)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1214)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BasePythonUDFRunner$PythonUDFWriterThread.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:451)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1928)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:282)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:398)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
    ... 26 more

I tried different answers from different forums tackling the same problem, but they are all suggesting trying Findspark or checking the version of my Java that is correct for me.
Anyone encountering the same error?
